# Controller not rendering in erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've set up a post controller for a simple blog.

However nothing is happening, the ruby isn't displaying in any of the tags from the controller. It's just coming up as empty. I've attatched my pages + posts_controller.rb page I've followed the instructions from this tutorial https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-blog-with-ruby-on-rails-part-1

I'm sure im just missing something small, just starting out on rails!

show.html.erb

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8">
   <h2><%= @post.title %></h2>
   <p class="lead"> <%= raw @post.body %>
```

index.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-12 blog-content">
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="text-center">
        <h2><%= post.title %></h2>
        <h6></h6>
      </div>

      <div>
        <%= raw(post.body).truncate(358) %>
      </div>

      <div class="text-center">
        <%= link_to "READ MORE", post_path(post) %>
      </div>
      <br>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Posts Controller:

```
    class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_post, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :delete]

  # Index action to render all posts
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # New action for creating post
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # Create action saves the post into database
  def create
    @post = Post.new
    if @post.save(post_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created post!"
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Error creating new post!"
      render :new
    end
  end

  # Edit action retrives the post and renders the edit page
  def edit
  end

  # Update action updates the post with the new information
  def update
    if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated post!"
      redirect_to post_path(@posts)
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Error updating post!"
      render :edit
    end
  end

  # The show action renders the individual post after retrieving the the id
  def show
  end

  # The destroy action removes the post permanently from the database
  def destroy
    if @post.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully deleted post!"
      redirect_to posts_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Error updating post!"
    end
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
  end

  def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you already check via `rails c` if you have records saved in your `posts` table?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing routing, add into config/routes.rb file.

```
resources :posts
```

Comment: How did you know? If he doesn't have that route, it will show an error. You can notice in his post `However nothing is happening, the ruby isn't displaying in any of the tags from the controller. It's just coming up as empty.` that he is not getting an error, object is not displaying.

Comment: thanks @araratan it's true. I have included
    resources  :posts into my routes

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no data in your `Post` table. Just follow below steps to check and create a record.

1. Go to rails console by using command: `rails c`.
2. Check the record count by using query: `Post.all.count`
3. If it returns count `0` then you should create record first by using the query: `Post.create(title: "Sample title" , body: "Sample Body")`

Comment: Yep, i did this one and the posts are certainly saving into the table. Even on the index page there are 4x "read more" links. Indicating that it's saved. It's just the actual inputs into the form that aren't displaying

Answer (score 0):

In the create action in the controller, you are doing:

```
if @post.save(post_params)
```

you should not pass post_params to save method, but to new or create. The posts are getting created, but the title and the body are not being saved.

Try instead:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  if @post.save
  ...
```